# Reading BSD500 groundTruth with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, scipy

I am trying to load using scipy `loadmat` a ground truth file, it return numpy ndarray of type object (`dtype='O'`).

From that object I arrive to access to each element that are also ndarrays but I am struggling from that point to access to either the segmentation or the boundaries image.

I would like a to transform this a list of list of ndarray of numerical types how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix my issue.
I do not think it is optimal but it works.

```
def load_bsd_gt(filename):
    gt = loadmat(filename)

    gt = gt['groundTruth']

    cols = gt.shape[1]

    what = ['Segmentation','Boundaries']

    ret = list()

    for i in range(cols):
        j=0
        tmp = list()
        for w in what:
            tmp.append(gt[0][j][w][0][0][:])
            j+=1
        ret.append(tmp)

    return ret
```

If someone have a better way to do it please feel free to add a comment or an answer.